# Forwarding a subdomain to a Minecraft Server

Tags: dns, subdomain, domain-forwarding

I am trying to forward a subdomain to directly connect to a Minecraft server. The domain name is hosted at GoDaddy and the server requires the port at the end. These are the things I have tried so far:

1. I attempted to create an `A` record via GoDaddy's DNS manager. This worked in redirecting the IP, as the IP for the server is actually the IP for the server's control panel. I attempted to add this to Minecraft followed by `:25602` which is the port number. Unfortunately that didn't work.
2. I went to the GoDaddy domain management page and attempted to create a redirect to the subdomain but that did not work either. I entered the port name as well.

Does anyone know how to do this successfully? I mean to me, these things should have worked. I have done some research and can't seem to find anything other than what I have tried already.

Comment: Dude, setting up a server or a sub domain yourself is very difficult. I am about 18 years old but I still could not create a server in the minecraft. I tried more than 10 times, but all the time I came across various DNS errors and not only. As a result, I was tired of all this and I decided to buy a seover from a friend...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake was attempting to add a port in step 1 and using words like forward. You want to POINT, not foward which I'll explain below.

DNS works by translating domain to ip addresses, it has nothing to do with ports. So for example if you have a website running on one ip but then your minecraft server is on another then you need to setup CNAME's which is a subdomain.

So your records might look like

```
@ > 192.0.2.123

www > @
```

Which means that the CNAME of `www` is running on IP address `192.0.2.123` etc.

Simply add a new cname and then enter the IP of the minecraft server. Your friends and co will be able to access the server via the sub domain 24 hours later roughly.

EXAMPLE:

SERVER as the CNAME, then the server IP. This makes the sub domain `server.yourdomain.example`

Comment: I will give this a try and tell you how it goes. Please forgive my terminology as I have only just started playing around with DNS stuff.

Comment: hey no problem at all. Let us know if it works. :P

Answer (score 2):

You don't want just an A record, you want an SRV record for minecraft. To connect with whatever.domain.tld to your minecraft server add

```
_minecraft._tcp.whatever.domain.tld.    IN SRV     0 5 minecrafts_port_number yourminecraftserver.domain.tld.
```

and then

```
yourminecraftserver.domain.tld.    IN A    servers.ip.address
```

It looks like taking a detour but this is the kosher, supported way and it gives you 1) the convenience of using any port without having your users type it in and 2) flexibility to potentially run another service, like a website, at the same address as the minecraft server (whatever.domain.tld). You can even use root/naked domain (domain.tld).

I don't know how to do it in Godaddy's panel. Google around or ask support how to add an srv record in general and it will be analogous.