# Using SRV records with a target domain that already has A records pointing elsewhere

Tags: domains, dns

First thing's first, I'm quite new to all of this stuff and will almost certainly use the wrong lingo here and there. I'm also not sure if I'm even in the right place to ask this. For both I apologise in advance!

I have a webpage hosted with GitHub Pages and in order to be able to use `example.com` instead of `www.example.com` it was required that I add 4 A records to my DNS pointing to the GitHub IP addresses.

I also have a minecraft server but this is at a different IP address to the webpage. I want to use an SRV record to point `minecraft.example.com` to the IP and port of this server but since an SRV record requires a "Target" domain I can't make it work.

I have tried adding another A record with the IP of the minecraft server alongside the A records for the website but this didn't work and from the reading I've done this probably shouldn't be the way to go about this.

Is what I'm trying to do possible or am I going to have to use `www.` for the website?

Comment: There are multiple questions./answers on the site already about Minecraft (which technically is not running a website so not sure it is really on topic here). See for example https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/72209/75842

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to change to `www` unless you want it. This will require to modify your CNAME file on GitHub also.

You just need to create the appropriate A record with a static IP of your Minecraft server, unless it is a dynamic IP, you should have a CNAME record rather than an A record pointing to some services like (EX: No-IP) to dynamically correct the record.

After that, just create the SRV record pointing directly to the record you have chosen (minecraft.example.com). with:

```
Protocol: _tcp
Priority: 0
Weight: 5
Port: [custom port] usually is: 25565
Target: minecraft.example.com
TTL: Automatic or 30 min
```

You need both records working SRV record, pointing the CNAME or A record of your WHATEVER.example.com